# How can I create semicircle progress bar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a half circle like that's shown in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ay8egkbu/3/). And the progress bar needs to have green color.

I am new to Jquery.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>100%</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: none;
}

p { 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ay8egkbu/3/)

Comment: you need to use some js plugins to do that. Check this: https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

Comment: just try knob jquery library i hop it's used full for you. http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/

Comment: @Dhaval Thankyou!  Googled! But no luck that's why am asking here

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to jQuery?! What's jQuery supposed to do in your case?

Comment: jQuery or Javascript to run the progress bar as per my percentage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.animate()` `step` on arbitrary values to control the `.bar` CSS3 `transform: rotate`

```js
$(".progress").each(function(){
  
  var $bar = $(this).find(".bar");
  var $val = $(this).find("span");
  var perc = parseInt( $val.text(), 10);

  $({p:0}).animate({p:perc}, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function(p) {
      $bar.css({
        transform: "rotate("+ (45+(p*1.8)) +"deg)", // 100%=180° so: ° = % * 1.8
        // 45 is to add the needed rotation to have the green borders at the bottom
      });
      $val.text(p|0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.progress{
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
}
.barOverflow{ /* Wraps the rotating .bar */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* Comment this line to understand the trick */
  width: 90px; height: 45px; /* Half circle (overflow) */
  margin-bottom: -14px; /* bring the numbers up */
}
.bar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 90px; height: 90px; /* full circle! */
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #eee;     /* half gray, */
  border-bottom-color: #0bf;  /* half azure */
  border-right-color: #0bf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>10</span>%
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>100</span>%
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>34</span>%
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>67</span>%
</div>
```

P.S: You *don't* need JS (it's doable in pure CSS3... unless you need to precisely control the progress steps)

Comment: Thank you this will work! but, is it possible to show total border in red and only completed process in green?

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf5jaohq/1/) Check this out. i need `bar` div on that red line.. that red line never have to move it stays as it

Comment: @parish Another idea, without using the `:before` would be to make the `.bar` a full circle (`90x90px`) and color border top and right in one color and bottom and left in the red color. Rotate it so that only the red is visible, and than using jQuery rotate the entire `.bar`.... you got the idea.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , can u guide on, how i can make the corners round ?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm afraid you cannot make round corners. Use some JavaScript plugin than that makes use of canvas.

Comment: i am an ionic developer am trying to implement your code but i am not able to see the animation part in my mobile ?? @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @MohanGopi when you open on your mobile this jsBin: http://jsbin.com/yiqepe/1/edit?html,css,js,output - do you see the animations? If yes than I'm sorry for your inconveniences - I have no experience yet with iconic.

Comment: we have `border-bottom-color: #0bf; border-right-color: #0bf;` this color to fill the semicircle instead of `#eee` is it possible that i can make an image to travel from left to right instead of `#0bf` @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: sure you can. Say you have a transparent circle, now imagine it's diagonally splitted like `/` you need to color only the right part. Than set such image as background-image and you're done. no borders needed. @MohanGopi

Comment: Are you able to provide the same example using <progress></progress> ?

Comment: I got this working thank you.  Is it possible to make the inner bar wider? I try but am not having any luck lol. I'm displaying like 3/4 of the circle so idk if that will work or not. Or if I could make the circle taller while still keeping it a half 180 degrees then that would be great also.

Comment: @DanielJackson yes, simply increment the border of `.bar` to make the **bar** thicker/wider. To make them bigger simply play with the 90px and 45px values. No, this solution is for half bars only.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ok I'll play with it but for now looks like the half circle will have to do. Thank you for the solution and the answer!