# How to move a div in semi circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic2

here is my .html file

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
    <div id="b" style="position:absolute;"> <img src="assets/Mostly_Cloudy.png" /> </div>
</div>
```

.css file

```
.progress{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: -52px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
.barOverflow{ /* Wraps the rotating .bar */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* Comment this line to understand the trick */
  width: 200px; height: 100px; /* Half circle (overflow) */
  margin-bottom: -14px; /* bring the numbers up */
}
.bar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 200px; height: 200px; /* full circle! */
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #dedede;     /* half gray, */
  border-bottom-color: #ffde3e;  /* half azure */
  border-right-color: #ffde3e;
}

 div#b {
    width: 25%;
}
```

.ts file

```
  setTimeout(()=>{
      $(".progress").each(function(){
        var int = 100;
        var $bar = $(this).find(".bar");
        var $img = $(this).find("#b");
        var perc =100;
        $({p:0}).animate({p:perc}, {
          // duration: 1*12*60*60*1000,
          duration: 30*1000,
          easing: "swing",
          step: function(p) {
            $bar.css({
              transform: "rotate("+ (45+(p*1.8)) +"deg)", // 100%=180° so: ° = % * 1.8
              // 45 is to add the needed rotation to have the green borders at the bottom
            });
          }
        });

      $("#b").animate({left: "+="+perc},{
        duration:30*1000,
        easing:"swing"
      });

      });

    },100)
```

by referring this stack [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051691/how-can-i-create-semicircle-progress-bar-with-jquery/39052971?noredirect=1#) i got the idea of rotating but i am not able to move my image along with the rotation.

> how to make my image to travel along with the `.bar` div color.

[image: img]

this image is some where i wanted it to act like seeker for the line

actual image looks like this

[image: img]

Comment: The best way to do this is to use canvas.

Comment: simplest solution I can think of is to make the image be inside of a larger div (attached to it's top left. The div itself is "attached" to the bottom center of that whole thing and just rotate the whole div clockwise, while rotating the image counterclockwise at the same speed to make it seem as if it is just moving.

Comment: please look at my updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make some more modifications. Maybe will be what you expect.

```
 <div class="barOverflow">
<div class="bar">
<div id="b" style="position:absolute;"> <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-sun-clip_art_image_of_a_bright_sunshine_0071-0902-0318-3204_SMU.jpg" width="50px"/> </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nqc6tw5m/1/

Comment: thanks it helped me a lot one question i am not able to get my image as acutal image as you can see in my question. what i am getting now is  when i reach 100 % i am getting my image upside down sind the `.bar` is rotating i am getting my image also rotate @RobertNegreanu

Comment: I think Dellirium's answer is the answer for your question. You can modify your code used his example.

Comment: yes i got the solution after doing some small changes i am able to get the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it As per my comment on your post.

**[FIDDLEJS](https://jsfiddle.net/yh9r93vp/)** link

```
.large {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}

.small {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  animation-name: rotateCCW;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateCCW {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-180deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes rotateCCW {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-180deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can rotate the image in semi circle.
Modified the code from this post -  [How to make an image move in a circular path using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551380/how-to-make-an-image-move-in-a-circular-path-using-jquery)

```js
var t = 0;

function moveit() {
    t += 0.05;

    var r = -100;
    var xcenter = 100;
    var ycenter = 100;
    var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
    var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));
    $('#friends').animate({
        top: newTop,
        left: newLeft,
    }, 10, function() {
        if(newLeft<199)
        {
          moveit();
        }
        
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});
```

```css
#friends { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" 
id="friends"/>
```

Comment: Since this is not a straight line animation, we need to animate using curve path. Therefore we increment t += 0.05 and recalculate newLeft, newTop based on new value of t to form a curve. So we need to call moveIt recursively.

Comment: but see the code you are calling moveit() function inside the same moveit() function

Comment: yes that is required for recursion otherwise it wont continue to move along the curve path

Answer (score 1):

I did it in canvas way, adding some changes.
It is more performant approach with a spice of async frames.
Featuring transparent background.

```
<div class="progress">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/vector-clouds-png-KinejMzkT.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Source on codepen](https://codepen.io/Duelsik/pen/YQpXLr)